# In android development, how do you find out how many elements a spinner has?

Tags: android, spinner

I am adding items to my spinner dynamically from a MySQL Database. At the moment that the check is made I want to know how many items are in the dropdown list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following to get the number of items within the Adapter for the spinner:

```
mySpinner.getCount();
```

Answer (score 2):

[getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#getCount%28%29) returns how many items are in Spinner

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
spinner.getAdapter().getCount();
```